# Insert multiple records with join

Tags: join, sql-insert, postgresql-9.3

I need some help in figuring out how to insert more than one records in a table using a join (when the join returns more than one values). So here is the scenerio:

Table A:
`A_ID bigserial, Role Varchar(25), Description varchar(25)`

Table B: 
`B_ID bigserial, Role Varchar(25), Code varchar(25)`

**Table A and B are connected with column Role.**

Example Entries in Table_A:

```
1, A, Standard
2, B , Test
3, C, Test
4, D, Standard
```

Example Entries in Table_B:

```
1, A, ABC
2, B, XYZ
3, C, XYZ
4, D, ABC
```

Basically what I need to do is check for Roles where description = Test, then insert entry for this Custom Role to Table_B with Code = ABC (If entry doesn't exist already)

The following query will give me all the Test description Roles which do not have any entry with Code = ABC in table B

Query1:

```
SELECT ROLE FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.ROLE=B.ROLE
WHERE A.Description ='Test'
AND  B.CODE<>'ABC';
```

I have the following insert query:

```
insert into Table_B (Role , Code)
select  (SELECT ROLE FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.ROLE=B.ROLE WHERE A.Description ='Test'AND  B.CODE<>'ABC'), 'ABC';
```

The above insert query only works when Query1 returns one role, however I am not sure how to insert into table_A when Query1 returns more than 1 results.

Can someone pls help? Not looking to use Stored Procs for the same

Thanks.

Edited:

Example Entries in Table_A:

```
1, A, Standard
2, B , Test
3, C, Test
4, D, Standard
5, E, TEST
```

Example Entries in Table_B:

```
1, A, ABC
2, B, XYZ
3, B, ABC
4, C, DEF
5, C, XYZ
6, D, ABC
7, E, XYZ
8, E, LLL
```

Query1 will not work here:

```
SELECT ROLE FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.ROLE=B.ROLE
WHERE A.Description ='Test'
AND  B.CODE<>'ABC';
```

Using this query now:

```
SELECT distinct ROLE FROM TB  where role not in (
SELECT B.ROLE FROM TA A
INNER JOIN TB B
ON A.ROLE=B.ROLE
WHERE A.Description =Test
AND  B.CODE=ABC)
and role in (select role from TA where Description =Test);
```

How will the insert work now?

Answer (score 0):

You can make another column as 'Code'.

Something like:

`insert into Table_B (Role , Code)
SELECT ROLE, 'ABC' CODE FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.ROLE=B.ROLE WHERE A.Description ='Test' AND B.CODE<>'ABC';`

So number of columns will be match.

Comment: Edited my question. Can you pls help now?

Comment: insert into Table_B (Role , Code)
SELECT distinct ROLE, 'ABC' CODE FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.ROLE=B.ROLE AND A.Description ='Test'
AND B.CODE<>'ABC';